# How do I tell if I have successfully frozen or unfrozen a layer in Keras?

Tags: keras

How do you know when you've successfully frozen a layer in Keras? Below is a snippet of my model where I am trying to freeze the entire DenseNet121 layer; however, I'm unsure if that is actually occurring since the outputs to the console don't indicate what's happening.

I've tried two methods (1) `densenet.trainable = False` and (2) `model.layers[0].trainable = False`.

Furthermore, if I load the model again and add `model.layers[0].trainable = True`, will this unfreeze the layer?

```
densenet = DenseNet121(
    weights='/{}'.format(WEIGHTS_FILE_NAME),
    include_top=False,
    input_shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
)

model = Sequential()
model.add(densenet)

model.add(layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()

# This is how I freeze my layers, I decided to do it twice because I wasn't sure if it was working
densenet.trainable = False
model.layers[0].trainable = False

history = model.fit_generator(
                    datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE),
                    steps_per_epoch=len(x_train) / BATCH_SIZE,
                    epochs=NUM_EPOCHS,
                    validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
                    callbacks=callbacks_list,
                    max_queue_size=2
                   )
```

**Below is the output of `model.summary()`, which I would expect to indicate if a layer has been successfully frozen or not.**

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
densenet121 (Model)          (None, 8, 8, 1024)        7037504   
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d_3 ( (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 5125      
=================================================================
Total params: 7,042,629
Trainable params: 5,125
Non-trainable params: 7,037,504
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/100
354/353 [==============================] - 203s 573ms/step - loss: 0.4374 - acc: 0.8098 - val_loss: 0.3785 - val_acc: 0.8290
val_kappa: 0.0440
Epoch 2/100
354/353 [==============================] - 199s 561ms/step - loss: 0.3738 - acc: 0.8457 - val_loss: 0.3575 - val_acc: 0.8310
val_kappa: 0.0463
Epoch 3/100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> however, I'm unsure if that is actually occurring since the outputs to
>   the console don't indicate what's happening.

It does, as can be seen from the number of trainable parameters. As expected, only the parameters(5125) of the last Dense layer are trainable.

```
Total params: 7,042,629
Trainable params: 5,125
Non-trainable params: 7,037,504
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find whether a layer is frozen by looking at it's config:

```
>>> model.get_layer("dense_2").get_config()
{'name': 'dense_2',
 'trainable': True,
...
```

If trainable is `True`, it is unfrozen.